Can one trick android.widget.EditText to only activate edit-mode after a long click?
In my application I am displaying a spreadsheet-like matrix of "cells". The individual cells are EditViews.
I would like to create a behavior where a simple (short) click onto any cell selects the entire row while a long click enters the clicked cell's edit mode, i.e. the cell then gets "focused" and the edit cursor becomes visible and one can then edit that cell's content.
I am struggling to achieve this behavior. If I define the cells as (non-editable) TextViews I can register an OnClickListener which - on a short click - programmatically selects and thus highlights the entire row. But with a TextView one cannot switch into an edit mode, i.e. I can not edit that cell.
If I define all cells as EditTexts, then the short click directly enters edit-mode, i.e. even if I attach an OnClickListener that listener is not called and I can not select and highlight the entire row.
Is there a way to tweak the EditText behavior such that it lets short clicks "pass through" and it gets the focus only after a long click? I am considering to dynamically replace a long-clicked TextView by a corresponding EditText but that would trigger a screen refresh, loosing focus and all kind of side effects and sounds awfully complicated. Is there no simpler way?
Hope I could make myself clear...

Derive your own class from EditText and override onTouchEvent. You can then detect short and long clicks yourself before the EditText sees them.
Here is some code to handle onTouchEvent from one of my apps. It doesn't do what you want, but it shows how to write an override method for onTouchEvent.
    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (!isEnabled()) { return false; }
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mStartX = event.getX();
                mStartY = event.getY();
                // It is possible to get a down event when we think that the pointer
                // is already down: we abandon any action in progress.
                removeCallbacks(longClickTimer); // cancel any active timeout
                /* We give it twice the normal long click timeout because of the
                 * user's reaction time to see that they have
                 * touched the thumb before moving it.
                 */
                postDelayed(longClickTimer,
                    2L * ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout());
                mTimerRunning = true;
                mLongClicked = false;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (!mLongClicked) {
                    if (mIsDragging) {
                        trackTouchEvent(Math.round(event.getX()),
                                        Math.round(event.getY()));
                    } else if (mTimerRunning) {
                        switch (mDirection) {
                            case SLIDER_RIGHTWARDS:
                            case SLIDER_LEFTWARDS:
                                if (   (event.getX() - mStartX > mScaledTouchSlop)
                                    || (mStartX - event.getX() > mScaledTouchSlop))
                                {
                                    // real move action
                                    startDrag();
                                    trackTouchEvent(Math.round(event.getX()),
                                                    Math.round(event.getY()));
                                }
                                break;
                            case SLIDER_UPWARDS:
                            case SLIDER_DOWNWARDS:
                                if (   (event.getY() - mStartY > mScaledTouchSlop)
                                    || (mStartY - event.getY() > mScaledTouchSlop))
                                {
                                    // real move action
                                    startDrag();
                                    trackTouchEvent(Math.round(event.getX()),
                                                    Math.round(event.getY()));
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    } // else should be impossible
                } // else ignore it after deciding this is a long click
                break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (!mLongClicked) {
                        setPressed(true);
                        trackTouchEvent(Math.round(event.getX()),
                                        Math.round(event.getY()));
                        actionDone(); // calls setPressed(false)
                    } else { mLongClicked = false; }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                /* This is usually caused by a containing View
                 * in its onInterceptTouchEvent() method deciding that the user is
                 * doing a fling or a scroll, and it will take over handling of
                 * subsequent MotionEvents until it sees an ACTION_UP.
                 * However it can happen for other reasons.
                 */
                if (actionDone()) {
                    // Was dragging, jump back to where we started without animation
                    setValueInternal(mStartValue, false);
                }
                break;
        }
        requestFocus();
        return true; // if we're enabled, we always handle it
    }

Thw whole app is available at https://github.com/rparkins999/AndroidSecondsClock.

Thanks for the example and pointer. It took me some fiddling and peeking into your code but eventually I got it behaving like I want it to. Cheers!
